# loading tensorflow on Windows with new RTX-2080 NVIDIA card

Tags: tensorflow

Trying to load tensorflow with Windows 10 on a new RTX-2080 NVIDIA card (using Python). Are there existing binaries? Do I have to built from source? What versions of CUDA and Cudnn do I need?

Thanks,

Rich